# Change unsecure URL to secure including newsletter

Tags: magento-1.9

I just installed the SSL cert on the server but now am getting an error saying the secure pages are loading unsecure content. Examples below. I do not know where to find the URL in the code so I can change "http" to "https". Thank you for your time.

Here are the URLs I need to find and change to "https":
http://www.everydayblade.com/newsletter/subscriber/new/
http://www.everydayblade.com/catalogsearch/result/

Comment: maybe you need set unsecure url the same like secure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to System -> Configuration -> General -> Web and change your URLs there. If you set both to https everything should work. If this doesn't fix your issue it is possible your urls are hardcoded somewhere.